# Cant invoke POST requests when using swagger-ui and swagger-springmvc

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am running swagger-ui ver 2.1.3.

I am generating swagger docs using

```
com.mangofactory:swagger-springmvc:1.0.0
```

I annotated my spring-boot app with:

```
 @Bean
    public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin customImplementation() {
        return new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(this.springSwaggerConfig).apiInfo(
                apiInfo()).includePatterns("/.*");
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo("User Service", "API for UserService",
                "User Service API terms of service","blabla",
                "User Service API Licence Type", "User Service API License URL");
        return apiInfo;
    }
```

The json which is generated we can see:

```
    {
  "apiVersion": "1.0",
  "swaggerVersion": "1.2",
  "basePath": "/",
  "resourcePath": "/users",
  "produces": [
    "*/*",
    "application/json"
  ],
  "consumes": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "apis": [
    {
      "path": "/users",
      "description": "getMultiple",
      "operations": [
        {
          "method": "GET",
          "summary": "getMultiple",
          "notes": "getMultiple",
          "nickname": "getMultiple",
          "produces": [
            "*/*"
          ],
          "consumes": [
            "application/json"
          ],
          "parameters": [
            {
              "allowMultiple": false,
              "defaultValue": "",
              "description": "id",
              "name": "body",
              "paramType": "body",
              "type": "string",
              "required": false
            }
          ],
          "responseMessages": [
            {
              "code": 200,
              "message": "OK",
              "responseModel": "array"
            },
            {
              "code": 401,
              "message": "Unauthorized"
            },
            {
              "code": 403,
              "message": "Forbidden"
            },
            {
              "code": 404,
              "message": "Not Found"
            }
          ],
          "deprecated": "false",
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "PublicUserProfile"
          },
          "uniqueItems": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "path": "/users",
      "description": "create",
      "operations": [
        {
          "method": "POST",
          "summary": "create",
          "notes": "create",
          "nickname": "create",
          "produces": [
            "application/json"
          ],
          "consumes": [
            "application/json"
          ],
          "parameters": [
            {
              "allowMultiple": false,
              "defaultValue": "",
              "description": "input",
              "name": "body",
              "paramType": "body",
              "type": "User",
              "required": false
            }
          ],
          "responseMessages": [
            {
              "code": 200,
              "message": null,
              "responseModel": "object"
            },
            {
              "code": 201,
              "message": "Created"
            },
            {
              "code": 401,
              "message": "Unauthorized"
            },
            {
              "code": 403,
              "message": "Forbidden"
            },
            {
              "code": 404,
              "message": "Not Found"
            }
          ],
          "deprecated": "false",
          "type": "object"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "path": "/users/{userId}",
      "description": "getSingle",
      "operations": [
        {
          "method": "GET",
          "summary": "getSingle",
          "notes": "getSingle",
          "nickname": "getSingle",
          "produces": [
            "*/*"
          ],
          "consumes": [
            "application/json"
          ],
          "parameters": [
            {
              "allowMultiple": false,
              "defaultValue": "",
              "description": "userId",
              "name": "userId",
              "paramType": "path",
              "type": "string",
              "required": true
            }
          ],
          "responseMessages": [
            {
              "code": 200,
              "message": "OK",
              "responseModel": "PublicUserProfile"
            },
            {
              "code": 401,
              "message": "Unauthorized"
            },
            {
              "code": 403,
              "message": "Forbidden"
            },
            {
              "code": 404,
              "message": "Not Found"
            }
          ],
          "deprecated": "false",
          "type": "PublicUserProfile"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "models": {
    "PublicUserProfile": {
      "description": "",
      "id": "PublicUserProfile",
      "properties": {
        "userId": {
          "required": false,
          "type": "string"
        },
        "name": {
          "required": false,
          "type": "string"
        },
        "profileImageUrl": {
          "required": false,
          "type": "string"
        },
        "gender": {
          "required": false,
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "LocalDateTime": {
      "description": "",
      "id": "LocalDateTime",
      "properties": {}
    },
    "User": {
      "description": "",
      "id": "User",
      "properties": {
        "userId": {
          "required": false,
          "type": "string"
        },
        "name": {
          "required": false,
          "type": "string"
        },
        "profileImageUrl": {
          "required": false,
          "type": "string"
        },
        "gender": {
          "required": false,
          "type": "string"
        },
        "primaryEmail": {
          "required": false,
          "type": "string"
        },
        "createTime": {
          "required": false,
          "type": "LocalDateTime"
        },
        "activationTime": {
          "required": false,
          "type": "LocalDateTime"
        },
        "deleted": {
          "required": false,
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I do post it doesnt invoke it (however get requests work just fine)
trigger screenshot:

[image: swagger-post]

Why I have problems with posts using swagger-ui and POSTS

/user post service declaration:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
@Slf4j
class PublicUserServicesController {
..

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody User input) {

....
    return new ResponseEntity<>(user, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
..}
```

Comment: Could you please also include the declaration of the /users post service. Atleast the Annotations and the method signature?

Comment: @Zergleb of course. edited my question. let me know if anything else needed. thank you.